# How to execute two update statements in one transaction so they won't run into unique constraint in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Given models

```
from django.db import models


class RelatedTo(models.Model):
    pass


class Thing(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField()
    related_to = models.ForeignKey(RelatedTo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['n', 'related_to'],
                name='unique_n_per_related_to'
            )
        ]
```

and

```
>>> r = RelatedTo.objects.create()
>>> thing_zero = Thing.objects.create(related_to=r, n=0)
>>> thing_one = Thing.objects.create(related_to=r, n=1)
```

I want to switch their numbers (`n`).

In `update` method of my serializer (drf) I was trying to

```
@transaction.atomic
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    old_n = instance.n
    new_n = validated_data['n']

    Thing.objects.filter(
        related_to=instance.related_to,
        n=new_n
    ).update(n=old_n)
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

but it still runs into constraint.

`select_for_update` doesn't help either.

Is it possible not to run into this DB constraint using Django ORM or do I have to run raw sql to achieve that?

```
Django==3.1.2
```

```
postgres:12.5
```

Error

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_n_per_related_to"
DETAIL:  Key (n, related_to)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

Comment: Don't know if it will work but try using [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I assume it would work but seems weird not to call `super().update()` and use `bulk_update` instead. Anyway, that's the only solution I can think about as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve this issue neither with `bulk_update` nor with raw sql.

```
stmt = f"""
            update {to_update._meta.db_table} as t
            set n = i.n
            from (values
                ('{to_update.id}'::uuid, {n}),
                ('{method.id}'::uuid, {n})
            ) as i(id, n)
            where t.id = i.id
            """

with connection.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(stmt)
```

The only solution for this problem is making the column nullable and write 3 times to the table which physically hurts.

Comment: omg, i just found this after writing this detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74622094/django-swap-foreign-keys-of-one-to-one-relationship-in-an-atomic-transaction

it's insane to me that this is simply not possible!