# django - swap foreign keys of one-to-one relationship in an atomic transaction

Tags: django

i have a `Unit` model with a one-to-one related handler defined as such:

`handler = models.OneToOneField('users.Handler', related_name="unit_obj", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)`

i'm trying to update a set of units in an atomic transaction where the unit's `handler_id` foreign key can be set to null or any other `handler_id`. the problem is when handlers are being swapped.

i initially tried saving the updated unit inside an atomic transaction. but as soon as `unit.save()` is called on the first unit i get an integrity error because the second unit still has the same `handler_id`. i was hoping that the atomic transaction would defer the integrity error on individual `unit.save()` calls and only throw the error at the end of the transaction if there actually were any.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        for unit_model in unit_models:
            unit = Unit.objects.get(id=unit_model['id'])
            unit.handler_id = unit_model['handler']['id'] if unit_model['handler'] is not None else None
            unit.save()
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(f'Error saving units: {str(e)}')
```

then i tried using `bulk_update` which i was sure would solve the issue. unfortunately i get the same error (duplicate key value violates unique constraint) even though i have confirmed that there are no duplicates in the list. it still seems to be applying the saves sequentially, though that is not what i would have expected.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        bulk_units = []
        for unit_model in unit_models:
            unit = Unit.objects.get(id=unit_model['id'])
            unit.handler_id = unit_model['handler']['id'] if unit_model['handler'] is not None else None                
            bulk_units.append(unit)
        Unit.objects.bulk_update(bulk_units, ['handler_id'])
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(f'Error saving units: {str(e)}')
```

django's [constraint page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#deferrable) suggests that constraints can be `deferrable` which apparently defers them being enforced until the end of a transaction. that sounded great, until i discovered that `OneToOneField` does not expose any parameters for `deferrable` and there's a [feature-request page](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31583) where this is suggested to be too niche to be worth doing.

without this, the only way i can think to atomically perform a swap would be to first set all the unit's `handler_id` fields to `None` and then loop through the list and set them to their updated values. but am i missing something or understanding incorrectly? i don't see why it should be so difficult to atomically swap unique-constrained values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the limitation, for now, you can just add 1 more query to bypass it by setting everything to None before swapping

```
unit_models.update(handler=None)
```

Or you can use custom SQL migration to alter your unique constraint to deferrable.

```
ALTER TABLE package_unit ALTER CONSTRAINT unique_constraint DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: heh, not sure why i didn't consider manually altering the constraint to deferrable. that's probably the most reasonable solution, thanks!